# Table pulled from database to show on 5 columns (10 states on each column)

Tags: php, sql, database

I need help building a table in PHP that draws all the states from the database. I am a beginner and someone helped me with the pulling from the database, but I cannot seem to be able to put it in a table with 5 columns, and each column to have 10 states. Please help. This is the code I have for getting the states from the database:

```
<?php 

$states = $GLOBALS['db']->getAll('SELECT * FROM regions_tbl WHERE region_is_state = 1');


echo "<div class='statecolumn'><ul class='statelist'>";
$i=0; 
foreach ( $states as $state ) {
 $i++; ?>
 <a href='<?=HOST.$state['region_slug']?>.html'><?=$state['region_name']?>
<?php
if($i == 10)
   {
   echo "</ul></div><div class='statecolumn'><ul class='statelist'>";
   $i=0;
   }

}
echo '</ul></div>';
?>
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here.  What kind of output are you getting from this now?  What is the structure of your database?  Which part of this is not working?  How do you know the information is pulled from your database correctly?

Comment: Right now it just pulls all the states from the DB and lists them one by one - 10 on a row, the goes down to the next row, and so on until it finishes all the 50 states.
this is the link to see what i'm talking about
http://www.treeservicefinder.com/beta/

and I want them to look something like this 
http://dancestudioconnect.com/

Comment: Just fetch all of the states in an array and then iterate through five elements of the array at a time in order to make the rows of your table.

Comment: I just see 'Query Failed' when I follow the link.  But I think I see the problem -- posted an answer.

Comment: Alan, I was still trying stuff, that is why you sat Query Failed, try now

Comment: It would be helpful to know what your CSS is for statecolumn.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the li tag and the closing a tag.   Try this line replacement:

```
<li><a href='<?=HOST.$state['region_slug']?>.html'><?=$state['region_name']?></a></li>
```